# Email sent from Actionmailer does not read css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I am implementing an ActionMailer that sends out an email to the customer when a file is uploaded. I have a 0-10 rating system at the bottom of the email which I want should look different on the browser and phone app. 
The browser can only read inline CSS and not  but @media cannot be implemented using inline CSS.

I have tried using the "browser" gem but it doesn't work for mailers, only controllers. 
Using javascript hasn't helped either because the email is marked as Spam by Gmail in the browser.

Works for mobile app not browser:

```
<html>
<style>

body {
a:link, a:visited {
    border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #586674;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #6e7f91;
  color: white;
}

#nps-rating a:link, #nps-rating a:visited {
  width: 8.5%;
  font-size: 2em;

}

div{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:  #f2f2f2;

}

#nps-question {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#nps-options {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

.float-right {
    float: right;

}
.float-left {
    float: left;

}
#nps-legend {
    width: 100%;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#nps-rating a:link, #nps-rating a:visited {
   width: 250px;
   font-size: 2em;
   display:block; 

}
    #nps-options {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:block;

}
.float-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

}

.float-left {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nps-legend {
    width: 100%;}
}
</style>


WORKS FOR BROWSER NOT MOBILE APP


<p style="font-size: 2em;text-align: center;" >How likely would you be to recommend Carter &amp; Clark to a friend or colleague?</p>

            <div >
                <p style="float:left">0: Not Likely</p>
                <p style="float: right">10: Very Likely</p>
            </div>

            <br>

        <div >
            <% (0..10).each do |i| %>
                <%= link_to i, 
                "http://localhost:3060/nps_ratings/new_from_email? 
                order_id=#{@drawing.order_id}&user_id=# . 
                {@user.id}&rating=#{i}", 
                {:style=>'display:inline-block;
                    line-height:50px;
                    width: 75px;
                     font-size: 2em;
                     border-radius: 10px;
                      color: black;
                      border: 1px solid #586674;
                      padding-top: 15px;
                      padding-bottom: 15px;
                      margin: 0px;
                      text-align: center;
                      background-color: white;', :class => "css_class"}%>
            <% end %>

    </div>

</div>


</html>
```

the rating numbers should look like small buttons on browser and larger buttons : display:block; in mobile app